# jQuery autocomplete filtering incorrectly

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have an input field that has an auto complete jQuery field.

```
<input id="peopleRoleCodeAuto" type="text" size="50"/>
```

That when I type "A" I see "ATPL" value listed.  When I type "AT" it disappears, then when I type "ATP" it shows up again.  I have limited jQuery exposure and wondered if anyone had some suggestions.

```
        jQuery('#peopleRoleCodeAuto').icisAutocomplete({
        source: roleCodes,
        localJson: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        linkedFields: ['peopleRoleCode', 'peopleRoleCodeDescription'],
        select: function(event, ui){
            jQuery('#peopleRoleCode').val(ui.item.id);
            jQuery('#peopleRoleCodeDescription').val(ui.item.desc);
        },
        change: function(event, ui){
            jQuery('#peopleRoleCode').val(ui.item.id);
            jQuery('#peopleRoleCodeDescription').val(ui.item.desc);
        }
    })




 function icisAutocomplete(param, parentElem){
    return {
        source: param['source'],
        select: param['select'],
        search: param['search'],
        response: param['response'],
        focus: param['focus'],
        success: param['success'],
        change: function (event, ui) {
            if(jQuery(this).val() == ''){
                jQuery(param['clear']);
            }

            if(param['mustMatch'] && ui.item == null){
                jQuery(this).val('');
                if(param['linkedFields']){
                    clearFields(param['linkedFields']);
                }
            } else{
                if(param['change']){
                    jQuery(param['change'](event, ui));
                }
            }

            if(param['fieldsToResetOnChange']){
                clearFields(param['fieldsToResetOnChange']);
            }
        },
        minLength: (param['allOpt'] ? 0 : (!jQuery.isNaN(param['minLength']) ? param['minLength'] : 1)),
        allOpt: (param['allOpt'] ? true : false),
        delay: 0,
        autoFocus: true
    };
}
```

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

This started working once we add the following code searchOn: "id", to our jQuery code

```
jQuery('#peopleRoleCodeAuto').icisAutocomplete({
            source: roleCodes,
            localJson: true,
            mustMatch: true,
            linkedFields: ['peopleRoleCode', 'peopleRoleCodeDescription'],
            searchOn: "id",
            select: function(event, ui){
                jQuery('#peopleRoleCode').val(ui.item.id);
                jQuery('#peopleRoleCodeDescription').val(ui.item.desc);
                return false;
            },
            change: function(event, ui){
                jQuery('#peopleRoleCode').val(ui.item.id);
                jQuery('#peopleRoleCodeDescription').val(ui.item.desc);
                return false;
            }
        })
```